# Xtrabackup 2.4 : Skip tables during Incrementals backup but included them when creating the base backup

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-backups, percona

I wanted to avoid backing up some big tables during increments backup but including them every time I do a base backup.

I tried with `--tables-exclude` option but the tables got missing when restoring the data and only their tablespace exists.

Create Base backup:

```
xtrabackup --backup --target-dir=/data/xbackup_20181219_000000_base --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/ --user=root --password=****** --port=**** --no-lock --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --use-memory=20GB --parallel=20 2>&1
```

Create Incremental backup:

```
xtrabackup --backup --tables-exclude='mysql[.]test' --target-dir=/data/xbackup_20181219_000100 --incremental-basedir=/data/xbackup_20181219_000000_base --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/ --user=root --password=****** --port=**** --no-lock --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --use-memory=20GB --parallel=20 2>&1
```

Comment: Surley you have to restore the last basebackup first and **then** restore each of the incrementals you did IN THE ORDER YOU DID THEM since that basebackup. Simple logic

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I am doing when restoring the data, the base have the tables, but when applying the incrementals they got misssing

Comment: The whole point of doing Incremental backups is that is speeds up the backups. But you have to offset that against the fact is slows down the restore and make that process more complex. But you do that because you hope you will never actually need to do a full restore. It also means you only do as many incremental backups between Full backups as you are prepared to have to incrementally restore

Comment: So which tables got missed when restoring

Comment: The tables that I am excluding from incrementals backup

Comment: Are you sure that they were there after you restored the BaseBackup?

Comment: I didn't check that, I will test that and return to you,
But I am sure they were within the base when creating it and not in incrementals dir so --tables-excude is working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185493/discussion-between-ahammar-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: I don't want to try to answer the Question when something goes wrong with this abnormal backup technique.